# Unable to fetch Employee information from Workday using Get_Workers() ( python)

Tags: python, workday-api

I'm trying to fetch employee information from Workday using python using the Get_Workers method. However, it results in a failure. Is there any example available showing how to use it? The basic intention is to obtain the Employee's Location information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more information and code snippets (not the complete code) about what you've tried already.

Comment: The code I'm using to fetch the employee information is as follows:
result = client.service.Get_Workers(CustomerObjectType)
print result


I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    result = client.service.Get_Workers(CustomerObjectType)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 149, in get_reply
    soapenv.promotePrefixes()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here is an example that shows how to use the **suds** module
which is based on [this gist of which I am not affiliated with](https://gist.github.com/shacker/87908e13c9ee6655ce90).

This should provide a base that you can use to access whatever you need from [Get_Workers](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v32.0/Get_Workers.html)

```
import secrets

import sys

from suds import client
from suds.wsse import Security, UsernameToken
from suds.sax.text import Raw
from suds.sudsobject import asdict
from suds import WebFault

wsdl_url = 'https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/yourTenantHere/Human_Resources/v32.0?wsdl'
Employee_ID = '139420'
client = client.Client(wsdl_url)

security = Security()
token = UsernameToken(secrets.username, secrets.password)
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)

xmlstring = '''
<ns0:Worker_Reference>
    <ns0:ID ns0:type="Employee_ID">{id}</ns0:ID>
</ns0:Worker_Reference>
'''.format(id=Employee_ID)

xml = Raw(xmlstring)

try:
    result = client.service.Get_Workers(xml)
except WebFault as e:
    # Employee ID probably doesn't exist.
    print(e)
    sys.exit()

def recursive_asdict(d):
    """Convert Suds object into serializable format."""
    out = {}
    for k, v in asdict(d).items():
        if hasattr(v, '__keylist__'):
            out[k] = recursive_asdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in v:
                if hasattr(item, '__keylist__'):
                    out[k].append(recursive_asdict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out

worker_dict = recursive_asdict(result)
worker = worker_dict['Response_Data']['Worker'][0]['Worker_Data']
lname = worker['Personal_Data']['Name_Data']['Legal_Name_Data']['Name_Detail_Data']['Last_Name']

print(lname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried using this, but I get the same error: 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 149, in get_reply soapenv.promotePrefixes() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

I have downloaded the wsdl file locally and am referencing it using the following:
wsdl_url = urlparse.urljoin('file:', urllib.pathname2url(os.path.abspath("/home/...../Human_Resources.wsdl")))


This should not be a problem right? The issue is that the response has no soap envelop. Any suggestions on where I may be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, @PDsilva - I think we would need more information to help. I'd try to debug to find why your response is coming back without a soap envelope (or at all?). You could also try using the wsdl from your tenant to be sure that it is accurate.